# Please select a file Codeigniter Error

Tags: codeigniter

this code is not uploading any files says you did not select any file. can anybody tell whats the error/mistake.

```
public function upload_gallery() {
    $config['upload_path'] = 'gallery/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;
    $this -> load -> library('upload', $config);
    foreach($_FILES['gallery']['name'] as $images => $key) {
        if(!$this -> upload-> do_upload('gallery[]')) {
            echo $this -> upload -> display_errors();
            exit();
        }
        else {
            echo $_FILES['gallery[]']['name'] = $_FILES['gallery']['name'][$images];
            $uploaded = $this -> upload -> data();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also add your html code from your form?

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form? Use absolute path for image uploading directory. Something like `FCPATH . 'gallery/'` (`FCPATH` is [CI constant](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/reserved_names.html#constants) for location next to `index.php` file).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably uploading larger files, than you have allowed to be uploaded.
Try this or something like that:

```
    $config['max_width'] = '4000';
    $config['max_height'] = '4000';
    $config['max_size'] = '700000';
```